# c#, SQL, PetaPoco Создать таблицу если ее не существует

Tags: c#, sql

Не понимаю как создать через PetaPoco таблицы соответствующие к созданной модели БД

Comment: А что значит "соответствующие к созданной модели БД"?

Comment: Есть набор классов которые соответствуют таблицам БД. Если в БД нету некоей таблицы -- нужно ее создать т.к. класс существует.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы используете PetaPOCO — это одна из MicroORM. MicroORM — очень тонкая прослойкой между SQL и примитивными классами на C# (POCO). То что вы пишите больше подходит к большим ORM вроде Entity Framemework (и то, только с подходом Code First).

Поэтому лучшие способы это сделать:

1. Вручную добавить таблицы с помощью SQL.
2. Написать код, который будет генерировать SQL, который будет делать то, что вы написали. Можете к примеру добавить его при старте приложения и проверять наличие таблиц, затем если нужно то их и создавать. В этом вам поможет рефлексия (для извлечения нужных классов C#) и выборка по метаданным БД (чтобы понять какие таблицы есть).

Comment: мня и интересует есть ли элегантный способ это сделать, вместо того что бы идти этими путями :) А Энтити черезчур медленный и увесистый... Но в целом я понял...

Comment: @Andrew написать код, который ходит по метаданным БД и сборки — очень даже изящный способ. Увесистая ORM будет делать то же самое.

Comment: Эт я понимаю, просто был уверен что такую задачу через PetaPOCO тоже можно решать =( Это было как бы ожидаемо... Или же какое-то дополнение до него. Или мож у кого завалялся готовый код :)